# Javascript string.replace not working with my arrays, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

So I have three Arrays:

- str (containing the strings in which I want to replace something)
- replace (containing the letters to replace)
- by (containig the new letters)

Here's my code, it goes through the function but returns the same as it gets. The goal is for it to replace "W" with "0", "B" with "1" and so on. What am I doing wrong?

```
function internalArtNrGenerator() {

    var str = new Array("5 1 1 1 0 W 1 1", "5 1 1 1 0 B 1 1", "5 1 1 1 0 K 1 1");
    var replace = new Array("W", "B", "K", "M", "A", "S", "N");
    var by = new Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");

    function str_replace(replace, by, str) {
        for (var i = 0; i < replace.length; i++) {
            str = str.replace(new RegExp(replace[i], "g"), by[i]);
        }
        return str;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're defining the function `str_replace`, but you never make use of it. You're saying "if, within `internalArtNrGenerator`, someone wants to make use of the function `str_replace`, here's that function", but nothing ever makes use of it.

Reading the code it also looks confused. The idea with a function is that you call it and that you send the data into it by using *parameters*:

```
function addTwoNumbers(a, b) { return a + b; } // here, the parameters are a and b
addTwoNumbers(4, 2);
```

You're using the variable names `str`, `replace` and `by` as if they will automatically map to the parameters with the same name. That's not what happens. Those parameter names are just what the values you send in will be called within that function:

```
var x = 42; var a = []; var b = "something else";
var result = addTwoNumbers(x, 77); // does not at all touch the variables a and b above
// when addTwoNumbers is being run, a will be 42 (the value of x) and b will be 77
var secondResult = addTwoNumbers(8, 92);
// now when addTwoNumbers is being run, a will be 8 and b will be 92
```

Comment: Do I have to specifically call it if it's part of another function which gets called?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call the method on a string for it to work. For example, you can map your `str` array with `str_replace` to get the results. Note that it's kind of unclear because the `str` variable name is re-used.

```js
function internalArtNrGenerator() {

    var str = new Array("5 1 1 1 0 W 1 1", "5 1 1 1 0 B 1 1", "5 1 1 1 0 K 1 1");
    var replace = new Array("W", "B", "K", "M", "A", "S", "N");
    var by = new Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");

    function str_replace(replace, by, str) {
        for (var i = 0; i < replace.length; i++) {
            str = str.replace(new RegExp(replace[i], "g"), by[i]);
        }
        return str;
    }
  
    // The .bind creates a new method with the first 2 arguments bound,
    // .map passes the last one: the actual string to perform the action on
    // and returns a new array
    return str.map(str_replace.bind(null, replace, by));
}

console.log(internalArtNrGenerator());
```

Comment: Tried it just like that and got the same result as before.

Comment: If you run the code snippet in my answer, you get `"5 1 1 1 0 0 1 1",
  "5 1 1 1 0 1 1 1",
  "5 1 1 1 0 2 1 1"`, right? Wasn't that what you were aiming for?

Comment: You're right I'm sorry. Just didn't get it to run in my code.

Comment: Would it help if I add some more explanation to my answer?

Comment: It's working now, I took your code, pasted it into mine, compared it saw what was wrong corrected it and it's running now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check this Plunkr : **http://plnkr.co/edit/DYNk2kbjJfxGlEDZSnrT?p=preview**

You will need to call the function. & since your `str` is an array & not a string, iterate over it & pass it to the function.
(There are better methods for iteration).

```
function internalArtNrGenerator() {

    var str = new Array("5 1 1 1 0 W 1 1", "5 1 1 1 0 B 1 1", "5 1 1 1 0 K 1 1");
    var replace = new Array("W", "B", "K", "M", "A", "S", "N");
    var by = new Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");

    function str_replace(replace, by, str) {
        for (var i = 0; i < replace.length; i++) {
            str = str.replace(new RegExp(replace[i], "g"), by[i]);
        }
        return str;
    }

   for(var x in str)
   {
   str[x] = str_replace(replace,by,str[x]);
   console.log('inside');
   console.log(str[x]);
   }
   return str;
}

var x = internalArtNrGenerator();
console.log('final');
console.log(x);
alert(x);
```